# Programmatically get value from HtmlOutcomeTargetLink

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

We have a PrimeFaces data table that we like to export to Excel. The columns are defined like:

```
<p:column headerText="#{msg['common.number.label']}"
          width="60">
    <h:link id="insiderlist-id-action-link"
            value="#{value.id}"
            outcome="/view/insiderlistmgmt/insiderListManager"
            target="_blank">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{insiderListManager.getEncryptedValue(value.id.toString())}" />
    </h:link>
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="#{msg['common.name.label']}"
          width="120">
    <h:link id="insiderlist-name-action-link"
            value="#{value.name}"
            outcome="/view/insiderlistmgmt/insiderListManager"
            target="_blank">
        <f:param name="id" value="#{insiderListManager.getEncryptedValue(value.id.toString())}" />
    </h:link>
</p:column>
```

The data table shows clickable links that will make the user navigate to some other application/page via GET. The actual interest are the `value="#{value.id}"` and `value="#{value.name}"` attributes of each `<h:link>`.

The columns are defined in a general Facelet so the data table variable `value` is simply a standard JPA entity, depending on the use case (usually all of them have `getId()` or `getName()` methods).

The code for the exporter is:

```
public MyExporter extends AnotherExporter
{
    @Override
    protected String exportValue( FacesContext context, UIComponent component )
    {
        if ( component instanceof HtmlOutcomeTargetLink )
        {
            ELContext elContext = context.getELContext();

            HtmlOutcomeTargetLink link = ( HtmlOutcomeTargetLink ) component;            
            ValueExpression valueExpression = link.getValueExpression( "value" );

            Object expressionValue = valueExpression.getValue( elContext );
            Object linkValue = link.getValue();

            System.out.println( "<h:link value=" + expressionValue + "/" + linkValue + ">" );

            ... // return correct value etc.
        }

        return super.exportValue( context, component );
    }
```

The `System.out` you see there **always** prints:

```
12:13:07,344 INFO    [] (160) <h:link value=null/null>
12:13:07,344 INFO    [] (160) <h:link value=null/null>
12:13:07,356 INFO    [] (160) <h:link value=null/null>
12:13:07,357 INFO    [] (160) <h:link value=null/null>
12:13:07,357 INFO    [] (160) <h:link value=null/null>
12:13:07,371 INFO    [] (160) <h:link value=null/null>
```

**QUESTION**:

How do you **programmatically** find the value (as displayed/evaluated) of an `<h:link>` as specified above?

Comment: Custom exporter is unnecessary as `HtmlOutcomeTargetLink` extends `UIOutput` implements `ValueHolder`, which is already supported by default exporter (just calling `getValue()` was been sufficient). If you still keep getting null/empty strings, it's more likely that the data model has changed during the export as compared to during the display.

Comment: The custom exporter **is** necessary due to a different Excel output. The customer wants to flatten the sub tables and not nest them (`AnotherExporter` is pseudo code, MyExporter is actually a PrimeFaces Extensions subclass).

Comment: OK. Have you checked the integrity of the data model? That would be my first suspect. Code looks OK so far, albeit a bit clumsy (as said, `getValue()` was been sufficient).

Comment: Yeah LOL, the code is clumsy. It's pure desparation after a few things didn't happen to work out. I have to check the data model then. Thanks for the tip. I wonder why anybody would change the data model during the export.

Comment: It's effectively a new request. So perhaps bean is request scoped and/or it's doing request parameter dependent business logic in a getter method or (lazy) loader.

Comment: Hmmm sounds logical. It must be a new request of course. The bean the export action is called on however is `@ViewScoped`. I'll probably have to find out about the latter cause/s you mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79020/discussion-between-kawu-and-balusc).